# linking opencv libraries included as an external project via cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, static-linking

I'm relatively new to cmake and after days of struggling couldn't figure out the following thing:

I have a project that depends on opencv (which is a cmake project on its own) and I want to statically link opencv libraries. What I'm doing is I have a copy of opencv source code in my project and include it into my CMakeLists.txt via

```
ExternalProject_Add(my_copy_of_opencv_project
   CMAKE_ARGS -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=NO ...
   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${MY_OPENCV_INSTALL_DIR} 
   SOURCE_DIR ${PATH_TO_OPENCV_SRCS} 
)
```

All built nicely and where I have problem is that I cannot reliably determine where the opencv libraries will be. E.g. on linux/mac there are in `${MY_OPENCV_INSTALL_DIR}/lib` and are named as `libopencv_core.a` whereas on 32-bit Windows with VS 2012 installed the libs are in `${MY_OPENCV_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/x86/vc11/staticlib` and for the Debug configuration the libs named like `opencv_core247d.lib`.

So the question is can I somehow obtain a list of all libraries produced by the OpenCV build (and the root lib folder) and link them via something like `target_link_libraries(mylib opencv_core ...)`?

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or overcomplicated. So what I basically want is to compile my embedded opencv source tree statically and link against its libraries in a "cross-plaformish" way.

Any pointers are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't consider this question a duplicate; this question is about having "a copy of opencv source code in my project and include it into my CMakeLists.txt", the associated dupe is about using the system installed OpenCV

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best solution to use cmake with OpenCV project is:

1. Compile OpenCV as shared / static libraries with OpenCV's cmake build system.
2. In your project's CMakeLists.txt

For example (CMakeLists.txt):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(test_project)

# OpenCV_DIR could also be read from system environment variable.
if(WIN32)
  set(OpenCV_DIR "d:/libs/opencv-2.4.8/build")
else()
  set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/lib/opencv")
endif()
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS core imgproc highgui)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # not needed for opencv>=4.0
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

It works in cross-platforms.

Comment: Thanks! It already gave me pretty good insights. I'm just wondering how can I achieve the same thing without compiling OpenCV as a separate step, but rather integrate everything into one CMake project? Thanks!

Comment: If you copy the whole OpenCV project into your project directory. For example: <your_proj>/opencv, that you could just include opencv in your CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(opencv), then you could target_link_libraries(mylib opencv_core) directly, as the opencv modules are parts of your project.

Comment: Thanks I will give it another try. I remember I actually started with it, but then failed for reasons I no longer remember. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Hi @Vyacheslav, have you any news about this?